# Sefer guidebook to Understanding Aggadata Perspectives

Tags: product-recommendation, agada-stories-legends

I'm on the lookout for a sefer (ideally that is on Otzer Hachochmo or Hebrewbooks) that delves into the diverse ways of interpreting Aggadata Gemaras, if such a resource exists.  What I'm after is a comprehensive manual that explores the various commentaries and interpretations of Aggadata.

To illustrate, I'd like to explore approaches like the Marsha approach, to agdata is this, substantiated by examples from these specific Gemaras and his commentary Similarly, I'm interested in the Ramchal approach, which revolves around Y, and so forth.

Comment: I’ve yet to find any unfortunately, would you like me to recommend you some english books or YouTube shiurs on Aggadata/midrash?

Comment: https://www.amazon.com/Fresh-Fruit-Vintage-Wine-Ethics/dp/1602800081/ref=asc_df_1602800081/?tag=hyprod-20&linkCode=df0&hvadid=563715217888&hvpos=&hvnetw=g&hvrand=14057423926410156069&hvpone=&hvptwo=&hvqmt=&hvdev=m&hvdvcmdl=&hvlocint=&hvlocphy=9058691&hvtargid=pla-862222364328&psc=1&gclid=CjwKCAjwloynBhBbEiwAGY25dPs_t5ISOfzPo0c3K9wyO5uFY0tnEjofXTwMFRSfwzVVBmpMhQss7RoCELUQAvD_BwE

Comment: revolves around Y?

Comment: I would really prefer a sefer... something which can be more in depth

Comment: שיעורים באגדות חזל has a volume per tractate. 22 volumes available here, for example https://tinyurl.com/3wdbx88n - delves into all Aggadata Gemaras, but is not available online, as far as I can tell.

Comment: Why do you assume that these approaches are substantially different? The similarities are more striking than the differences, which tend to be more about format: Maharsha dealt with individual statements, and Ramchal wrote works on specific topics.